# How to decrease the height of ion-segment-button

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have tried to set the `padding` and `margin` to `0px` but still the height didn't decrease.

```
ion-segment-button {
  --padding-bottom: 0px;
  --padding-top: 0px;
  --margin-bottom: 0px;
  --margin-top: 0px;
}
```

I cant find any properties in the [documentation](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment-button/#css-custom-properties) that I cant tweak.

Answer (score 5):

You can set height like this..

```
ion-segment-button{
    min-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: still wont work but doing ```ion-segment{max-height: 10px}``` will do reduce the height but the segment button will not work propertly.

Comment: You can use ion-segment-button {
  height: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

Answer (score 3):

Need to decrease height and min-height. it should work.

```
ion-segment-button {
  height: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="segment" value="0">
    <ion-segment-button value="0">                                             
        Active                                                                 
    </ion-segment-button>                                                      
    <ion-segment-button value="1">                                             
        Expire                                                                 
    </ion-segment-button>                                                      
</ion-segment>
```

CSS:

```
ion-segment-button {
    min-height: 32px;
}
```

This works for me. Also, check if it is taking some height so that we can manage accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the min height alone will cause the text in your buttons to be cropped. Here is how to resize the button's height and have the text come down into the new center:

```css
ion-segment-button{
    height: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
ion-segment-button ion-label{
    margin:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me: (you have to define the height a ion-segment-button)

```
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="relationship" color="primary" >
    <ion-segment-button value="friends" style="height: 30px; font-size: 8px">
      Friends
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="enemies" style="height: 30px; font-size: 8px">
      Enemies
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, BTW it was on ionic 4. On what version of ionic you test that?

Comment: I tried it on 3.9.X (I dont know the exact version but it wasnt Ionic 4)

Answer (score 0):

I did like this in css

```
ion-segment{
  height:30px;
}

ion-segment-button{
   min-height:30px;
}
```